# Traduko de [de] "Pfanne" [en] "Flash Pan" [nl] "Kruitpan"

Tags: translation

Saluton!
Mi volas traduki la raporton de Dr. Paul Haller pri sia vojaĝo al la 10a Universala Kongreso en Parizo en la jaro 1914, kiu pro konataj kialoj ne okazis. En la raporto troviĝas la sekva frazo (en la germana):

"[...]eine Hand zeigte in stark vergrößertem Bilde, wie die Pfanne des franzosischen Gewehres 8, die des deutschen dagegen nur 5 Patronen faßt[...]"

En la angla eble:
"one hand showed in a greatly enlarged picture, as the flash pan of the French rifle holds 8 cartridges, while the German holds only 5"

Kiel traduki "Pfanne" au "flash pan" esperanten?

Comment: La citaĵo enhavas terminologian mison, nome ke tio, kion nomas angla "flash pan" ktp. jam 1914 estis eksmoda de 100 jaroj. Kion sinjoro Haller priskribas, estas tre verŝajne (interna) magazeno. Tio tamen ne respondas la finan demandon. Ĝis nun mi ne povis trovi terminon por tiu parto kaj ne volas simple proponi ion, kvankam "pulvopateto" eble estus bone komprenebla.

Answer (score 2):

Cyril pravas: 'Pfanne' en 1914 eble estis komprenata kiel rezervejo de kartoĉoj. Nuntempe oni eble pli bone uzu priskribantan terminon de la ideo en la frazo: pretigujo (de kartoĉoj).

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus "pulvujo" por "flash pan".

Comment: Kion signifas ‘pulvono’? Mi ne povas trovi tiun vorton. Kial ĉi tio estas laŭ vi la ĝusta termino?

Comment: Pulvono = (en) gunpowder, (de) Schießpulver, (nl) buskruit ("eksploda pulvoro").

Comment: Ne, tio estas _pulvo_. Mi ne certas, ĉu _pulvujo_ estas sufiĉe preciza por la demandinto, ĉar _pulvujo_ povas esti simpla ujo por stoki pulvon.

Comment: HO!  Joffysloffy, vi tute pravas!  Mi bedauxras--mi devintus kontroli pli bone.  Mi sxangxigis la vorton en mia respondo.

Comment: Bone, ke vi ja ŝanĝis vian respondon tiel, ke ĝi nun estas gramatike ĝuste.